# I need advice (online menu)

Tags: system

Thanks for checking this post out!

I run a small cafe, and i wish to make my staff members lives easier with a new ordering system!

I want to make a simple web-based application that will transmit data to another screen. For example;

1. On the tablet/laptop i will input the customers order
2. The staff  will see the order on a monitor in the kitchen
3. The staff member will have the ability to remove order that have
   gone out

I wish to create this system myself as a mini-project, and was wondering what the easiest method is for doing this? The system does not need to be complex, but just needs to function.

How can i do this?

Thank you again!

Comment: Kindof broad. You could go Cloud + Server + Client + Webserver + .... . You could also put a kindof "file" on a shared folder on a NAS that all have access to and modify it (urks). You could use a small local DB - plenty of options. Choose a language to proc in, start it, come back when you have concrete problems or hangups we could help with. This questions is kindof offtopic due to : Ask for library, Size of problem, etc.. Simplest would be to use what you know already so the learning curve is not very steep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are some design considerations that you will need to make decisions about first.

1. Do you want this to be a web application, or a standalone application (winforms)?  May I suggest that you create this as a web app, because if you do it right, it could work on smart devices then as well.
2. You will also need to consider security, because you wouldn't want just any computer/smart device to place or modify orders.
3. Do you have the hardware for hosting your solution, or will you want to consider using a cloud service.  There are many pros and cons either way, it's really just a decision you will need to make.

Comment: Yes, i am thinking of doing this on a Web App as i have in the past done something similar but forgot how i did it due to it being so long a go!

Comment: Basically

Laptop A will have bunch of options for foods to be selected; once the staff picks the order, and confirmed payment ...LAPTOP B will receive the order in some table form..

Comment: How do you want Laptop B to "receive" the order from Laptop A?  do you have a local network where they could simply share a file?  One of the trickiest issues when starting a project like this is managing scope.  You could "simply" share a file on the network, but then there are complications that you will need to deal with, like file locking, which could be handled better if you used a database.  I know that sounds like scope creep, but in the long run a database would be a much better place to manage the information that you are wanting to share between devices.

Comment: i was thinking of running two web pages

Comment: Page A is where the staff would put in the order
Page B is where the order would be viewed

Answer (score 0):

For a small mini project like this, I might go with something like "Comet" it's super easy and fast to build apps like this, and since it's a single restaurant you won't have to worry about scalability.

Whatever you decide to use, use some kind of framework, there is always a learning curve, and you will feel like you aren't getting anywhere, but it pays HUGE dividends in the end.

If you wanted to go the php route, use something like cakephp,  everyone will say Laravel but the learning curve for Laravel is much steeper than it is for other less flexible but more compact frameworks.  Unless you have plenty of time, and you want to learn laravel, then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would need to build an API which is connected to the database. Then, you need to build the front-end which will be displayed on the monitor.

For the API I would suggest `Node.JS` together with `Express`. I would recommend a database like `MongoDB`. You can look up a tutorial like: “REST API with express and MongoDB” on youtube.

The front-end doesn’t need to be pretty so just use an html `table` for the orders. However, it does need to request the data from your API, just use `jQuery` for this. You can also look up a tutorial on “jQuery http requests” for example.

Also, for security, I would consider using json-web-tokens together with your API. This makes it so that not everyone can access and modify your data.

I will admit, the learning curve for this is pretty big and it will take you a while,  but the finished product will be awesome.